# Find last update time of a directory (includes all levels of sub folders)

Tags: python, python-2.7

What is a good way to find out the last updated time of a directory? Note that this includes update to any levels of the subfolders as well. I know I can use `os.path.getmtime` or `os.stat` but they seem to work only if the immediate contents of the folder are changed. Do I need to recursively check for all subfolders and get the max modified time or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I think you will have to recursively check but that is pretty trivial

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `os.walk`...

```
m = max(map(lambda x: os.path.getmtime(x[0]), os.walk("directory")))
```

Comment: This is correct.  Someone care to explain? @user3885927?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. Edit history shows it was incorrect at some point, may be that's why you got a downvote from some visitor?

Comment: @user3885927 There was a syntax error using the lambda.  The code is still the same though.

Comment: I'll pop open a python interpreter before I post next time :).

Comment: I was going to do with  list comprehension like: max([x[0] for x in os.walk(directory)],key=os.path.getmtime) but seems your method has equal peformance. Picked your answer since no else posted one.

Comment: List comprehension is definitely more succinct.